# Does Backbone have a way to combine ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For example, after a certain event I do:

```
render: function () {
    new FavoritesView({el: $A.el('#mm'));
    new FeedView({el: $A.el('#at_view'));
    new AccountView();
}
```

which creates 3 views and 3 ajax requests.  Previously I was using a framework which only used one as it combined the request.

Is there a way to do this in Backbone?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are they all expecting the same response? Where does the request come into play here?

Comment: Are your views tied to different collections or one collection?

Comment: Each view has a separate model and or a separate collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide a lot of details or much code, but if there's a single request to retrieve multiple objects (as per your previous framework), then that request is most likely not really a REST interface. By default, Backbone expects to use a REST interface (Ruby-flavored) for its models (and, thus, collections), so there is no way to do what you want "out of the box."

Backbone, however, is easily extended, and you could certainly override the model/collections' `fetch` methods to use a non-REST API. An even better approach might be to make your own AJAX request for the three model/collections and then feed the appropriate data into the model/collection when creating it, thus avoiding the Backbone `fetch` altogether. Something like:

```
render: function() {
    $.getJSON("url/to/aggregated/data", function(data) {
        var favorites = new Favorites(data.favorites);
        var feed = new Feed(data.feed);
        var account = new Account(data.account);

        new FavoritesView({el: $A.el('#nm'), collection: favorites);
        new FeedView({el: $A.el('#at_view'), model: feed);
        new AccountView({model: account});
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer was good up until the last sentence and code example. Having views performing the role of a model is terrible advice.

Comment: not what I'd recommend either, but that's apparently what the original poster is doing. this answer is least disruptive to the OP's code.

Comment: MV* is good but it's nothing magical, there are many patterns you can use to architect code.